# Win7 screen resolution quick change

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I want to be able to create a shortcut, hotkey, anything, to be able to switch between 2 (or more?) different screen resolutions (only on one of my screens - I work with win7 extended screen layout).

I've tried HotKey Resolution Changer v1.4 from http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17604/change-desktop-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/ ,
but it works for me only for the first change and then crashes.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I had stumbled on this issue when starting to use KVM with Windows 7. It keeps forgetting the resolution and it became a hassle to change it. Anyway, to the point:

Download Nircmd from [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), extract it somewhere on your PC and create a desktop shortcut using Nircmd itself:

```
nircmd.exe cmdshortcut "~$folder.desktop$" "800x600x24" setdisplay 800 600 24
```

This will create a shortcut that will set the display mode to 800x600x24bit colors.

Hope it helps and not too late.

Asaf